# Determining elapsed time

Tags: php, datetime

I have two times in PHP and I would like to determine the elapsed hours and minutes. For instance:

8:30 to 10:00 would be 1:30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution might be to use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert your dates/times to timestamps :

```
$first_str = '8:30';
$first_ts = strtotime($first_str);

$second_str = '10:00';
$second_ts = strtotime($second_str);
```

And, then, do the difference :

```
$difference_seconds = abs($second_ts - $first_ts);
```

And get the result in minutes or hours :

```
$difference_minutes = $difference_seconds / 60;
$difference_hours = $difference_minutes / 60;
var_dump($difference_minutes, $difference_hours);
```

You'll get :

```
int 90
float 1.5
```

What you now have to find out is how to display that ;-)

*(edit after thinking a bit more)*

A possibility to display the difference might be using the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function ; something like this should do :

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$date = date('H:i', $difference_seconds);
var_dump($date);
```

And I'm getting :

```
string '01:30' (length=5)
```

Note that, on my system, I had to use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the timezone to UTC -- else, I was getting "02:30", instead of "01:30" -- probably because I'm in France, and FR is the locale of my system...

Comment: hmmm its not working, if  start clock is 4:11 and end clock is 20:13 my code says 17:02 amd that not ture, its to by 16:02, what mattere here :/

Comment: @NeoNmaN : did you try calling date_default_timezone_set ? When I'm not using it, I'm getting 17:02 too -- but when using it, I'm getting 16:02

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061472/strange-behavior-of-php-time-math-why-is-strtotime-returning-negative-numbers) to convert your times to integer values, then do the subtraction. From there you'll want to convert that result to units-hours-minutes, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: ...and then undo the conversion from the linked answer. You need to be careful about 12-hour time (AM/PM) vs 24-hour time.

Comment: and daylight savings time changeover days.  Have a look at the DateTime class.  It deals with all that.

Answer (score 0):

Use php timestamp for the job :

```
echo date("H:i:s", ($end_timestamp - $start_timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time1='08:30';
$time2='10:00';
list($h1,$m1) = explode(':', $time1);
list($h2,$m2) = explode(':', $time2);
$time_diff = abs(($h1*60+$m1)-($h2*60+$m2));
$time_diff = floor($time_diff/60).':'.floor($time_diff%60);
echo $time_diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$d1=date_create()->setTime(8, 30);
$d2=date_create()->setTime(10, 00);
echo $d1->diff($d2)->format("%H:%i:%s");
```

The above uses the new(ish) DateTime and DateInterval classes.  The major advantages of these classes are that dates outside the Unix epoch are no longer a problem and daylight savings time, leap years and various other time oddities are handled.