# Calculating the elapsed time

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407020/determining-elapsed-time)

I want to know how I can calculate the elapsed time beween 2 dates I have in a DB.

They are saved as 'EntryDate' and 'ExitDate' in date/time as DD-MM-YYYY 00:00:00 and I want to calculate the time between two for instance:

01.01.2012 12.00.00 and 01.01.2012 13.30.00 which would be 1hr 30 mins.

Thanks. Sam.

Comment: you want select query which gives you time difference?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [timediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff), when working inside mysql.

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00',
->                 '2000:01:01 00:00:00.000001');
-> '-00:00:00.000001'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the implementation in PHP you need to use [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function.

```
$d_start    = new DateTime($EntryDate); 
$d_end      = new DateTime($ExitDate); 
$diff = $d_start->diff($d_end); 

// return all data 
$this->year    = $diff->format('%y'); 
$this->month    = $diff->format('%m'); 
$this->day      = $diff->format('%d'); 
$this->hour     = $diff->format('%h'); 
$this->min      = $diff->format('%i'); 
$this->sec      = $diff->format('%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this forum thread: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/calculate-remaining-day-minute-seconds-between-two-dates-538979.html

Next time google a little before posting. We will help you but you shouldn't abuse...

Answer (score 0):

Because the dates are formatted like this, you can use `strtotime` to get the timestamps for each date. Then you just subtract the exit from the entry. This leaves you with the difference in seconds. Now you can play around with this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
eg:
select TIMEDIFF ('2006-10-31 11:50:31' , '2006-10-31 11:50:01')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2012-01-01 12:00:00','2012-01-01 13:30:00')
```

This will return the difference in minutes. You can replace Minute with any time unit (like 'HOUR', 'SECOND', etc.)