# strtotime returns wrong number?

Tags: php, strtotime

When I run this:

```
echo strtotime("January 1, 1970 00:16:00");
```

I get this:

```
-2640
```

How is this possible? I dont want a negative number, I want a positive number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061472/strange-behavior-of-php-time-math-why-is-strtotime-returning-negative-numbers

Answer (score 2):

Your timezone is set to GMT. Timestamps are in UTC, which is currently one hour behind GMT.

Comment: I am always struggling with timezones. I am in Europe/Amsterdam, my server has current time 17:13. What timezone have I need to set?

Comment: @Thijmen you can use `strtotime("January 1, 1970 00:16:00 GMT")` to get a positive number.

Comment: Thanks. What's the best practice with timezones when my laptop is currently in Europe/Amsterdam and having summertime?

Comment: UTC is never one hour behind GMT. Ever.

Comment: @salathe Excuse me? When GMT goes into Daylight Savings, it is one hour ahead of UTC, therefore UTC is one hor behind.

Comment: @Thijmen Preferred solution is `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: @Kolink - GMT is always the same as UST. When the clocks change for `daylight savings` in the UK we switch to BST (British Summer Time). GMT __never__ changes, and is __always__ the same as UST

Comment: @Kolink perhaps you're confusing the time us Brits follow (GMT in "winter", BST in "summer") with GMT?  As Mark detailed, GMT itself has no daylight savings boundaries (neither does BST): the Europe/London timezone (from the Olson timezone database) does.