# How to get seconds from a timestrong

Tags: php

I like to get the seconds from a string like `11.5 years`. Using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) return a negative value

```
strtotime('11.5 years', 0)
```

which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061472/strange-behavior-of-php-time-math-why-is-strtotime-returning-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution which works for my application

```
$value = 11.5;
$unit = 'year'; //day, second, month,...

$integer = floor($value);
$decimal = $value-$integer;

               //get value of full [unit] and at the percentage from the decmail
$delay = strtotime('+'.$integer.' '.$unit, 0)+strtotime('+1 '.$unit, 0)*$decimal
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo strtotime('+11 years 6 months');
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/adp3G5Ad)**

Comment: You beat me to it! +1

Comment: I get decimal values so like 11.123 years

Comment: You can use simple maths to convert those decimals to months and days

Comment: Not with a leap-year, in 11 years are at least two of them. Also I can get X day/week/hour/minute

Comment: i think this code returns the seconds of 2025 what if he wants the mesure long of 11 years in seconds? not the seconds past since 1970-01-01 02:00:00

Comment: Santa can you please elaborate on that comment a little?

Comment: Unless your string has a consistent format there's no magic method that can parse any string of any format and return the values correctly. You'll ve to write a parser first to extract the parts.

Comment: The format will always be `x [minute/hour/day/week/year]` where x can have decimals as well

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
echo strtotime('+11 years 6 months');
```